# ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I installed TensorFlow of version 2.0,c and import TensorFlow and when I ran it I got this error:

```
ERROR: Internal Python error in the inspect module
```

I'm using python 3 and Jupiter notebook. I don't understand why this error occurs. If someone could help me figure it out it would be great. This is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Below is the traceback from this internal error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):<br/>
  File "C:\Users\SalimSp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code<br/>
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)<br/>
  File "<ipython-input-6-d6579f534729>", line 1, in <module><br/>
    import tensorflow<br/>
  File "C:\Users\SalimSp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module><br/>
    from tensorflow_core import *<br/>
  File "C:\Users\SalimSp\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
```

Comment: Can you post the complete traceback? It seems to be incomplete.

Comment: Hello @Salim, kindly provide the complete installation details you have made.